# How to find all possible combinations in 2dArray with given string

Tags: javascript, algorithm

let's say I have simple 2d array

```
let array2d = [
   ['a','a','b'],
   ['a','b','c'],
   ['a','c','a']
]
```

and a simple string with random length, for example:

```
let string = 'abc';
```

How can I find all possible combinations of that string in given array where order matters?

so in this example result should be like that:

```
result = [
  [
     ['*','a','*'],
     ['a','b','*'],
     ['a','c','a']
  ],
  [
     ['*','a','*'],
     ['a','b','c'],
     ['a','*','a']
  ],
  [
     ['*','a','b'],
     ['a','*','*'],
     ['a','c','a']
  ],
  [
     ['*','a','b'],
     ['a','*','c'],
     ['a','*','a']
  ],
  [
     ['a','*','*'],
     ['a','b','*'],
     ['a','c','a']
  ],
  [
     ['a','*','*'],
     ['a','b','c'],
     ['a','*','a']
  ],
  [
     ['a','*','b'],
     ['a','*','*'],
     ['a','c','a']
  ],
  [
     ['a','*','b'],
     ['a','*','c'],
     ['a','*','a']
  ],
  [
     ['a','a','b'],
     ['*','*','*'],
     ['a','c','a']
  ],
  [
     ['a','a','b'],
     ['*','*','c'],
     ['a','*','a']
  ],
]
```

I have some thoughts on this one but i'm really not sure about those.

1. I thought about using array of coordinates for each letter in string, but I haven't figured out how to use it for random length of string
2. It might be easier to flatten array to 1 dimension and find indexes there. After that return the array back to 2 dimensions.

Comment: Can *"a simple string with random length"* be like `abxz` or `a` too?

Comment: It's not clear the relation among your inputs and your output. e.g. ..what are a, b and c in your input and output? vars? strings?

Comment: @Emadpres, yes it can. In case of abxz result should be empty array.

Comment: @Andrea, thank you for notice, 'a', 'b' and 'c' are 1 letter strings, i'll edit my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun little exercise actually, your thought nr. 2 was in the right direction. What I did was splitting up the task in two, 1. finding all the character locations, 2. recursively put together all the combinations.

```js
let array2d = [["a", "a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "c", "a"]];
let string = "abc";

var chars = string.split(""); //Convert string to [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
var dataAsString = array2d.map(function(d) {
  return d[0] + d[1] + d[2];
});
let concatedArrayString = dataAsString.join(""); //Convert array2d to "aababcaca"

let locations = findAllCharLocations(chars, concatedArrayString); // returns { a: [ 0, 1, 3, 6, 8 ], b: [ 2, 4 ], c: [ 5, 7 ] }
var result = [];
recursiveFindAllCombinations(0, array2d, locations, []);
console.log(result);
// The result is:
// [ [ [ '*', 'a', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ '*', 'a', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ '*', 'a', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ '*', 'a', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', '*', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', '*', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', '*', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', '*', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', '*' ], [ '*', 'b', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', '*' ], [ '*', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ], [ '*', '*', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ], [ '*', '*', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', '*' ], [ '*', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ '*', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', '*' ], [ '*', 'c', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', 'c' ], [ '*', '*', 'a' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', '*' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', '*' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', '*' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', '*' ], [ 'a', 'c', '*' ] ],
//   [ [ 'a', 'a', 'b' ], [ 'a', '*', 'c' ], [ 'a', '*', '*' ] ] ]

//Recursivly find all the combinations of a character at index, character array which is modified,
function recursiveFindAllCombinations(
  charIndex,
  characterArray,
  locations,
  currentCharIndexArray
) {
  //Copy the character array since we modifying it but dont want the other references to change
  let charArray = characterArray.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
  });
  //The current char
  let char = chars[charIndex];
  //For each location the character is found
  for (var index = 0; index < locations[char].length; index++) {
    //Copy the char index array 
    var newCharIndexArray = currentCharIndexArray.slice();
    var isAnOption = true;
    //Check and see if the new value is valid compared to the already choosen values.
    for (var check = 0; check < newCharIndexArray.length; check++) {
      let value = newCharIndexArray[check];
      if (value > locations[char][index]) {
        isAnOption = false;
      }
    }
    if (isAnOption) {
      //Example the first 'a' is found at
      // x = 0 % 3 = 0
      // y = Math.floor(0 / 3) = 0
      let x = locations[char][index] % array2d.length;
      let y = Math.floor(locations[char][index] / array2d.length);
      //Paint that location as found
      charArray[y][x] = "*";
      newCharIndexArray.push(locations[char][index]);
      //If there is more chars call recursively
      if (chars[charIndex + 1]) {
        //Use the next character in line
        recursiveFindAllCombinations(
          charIndex + 1,
          charArray,
          locations,
          newCharIndexArray
        );
      } else {
        //Since no more recursiv calls to do, push a copy of the charArray.
        result.push(
          charArray.map(function(arr) {
            return arr.slice();
          })
        );
      }
      //Reset the charArray
      charArray[y][x] = char;
    }
  }
}

//Find all the char locations
//Example returning : { a: [ 0, 1, 3, 6, 8 ], b: [ 2, 4 ], c: [ 5, 7 ] }
function findAllCharLocations(chars, concatedArrayString) {
  let charsCopy = chars.slice(0); //Make a copy on the char array.
  var locations = {};
  //Initiate the locations array { a: [], b: [], c: [] }
  for (var charIndex = 0; charIndex < charsCopy.length; charIndex++) {
    locations[charsCopy[charIndex]] = [];
  }
  var counter = 0;
  //As long as we havent found all the chars in 2d array continue
  while (counter != chars.length) {
    //Store the chars which we are done with and remove them after the loop.
    var charsToRemove = [];
    //Go through each char.
    for (var index = 0; index < charsCopy.length; index++) {
      let char = charsCopy[index];
      //Get the last index of that specific character, if nothing found yet this will be NaN.
      let lastIndexOfChar = locations[char][locations[char].length - 1];
      //Get the index of the next character
      let indexOfChar = concatedArrayString.indexOf(char, lastIndexOfChar + 1);
      //If a character was found push it to the location array
      if (indexOfChar != -1) {
        locations[char].push(indexOfChar);
      } else {
        //Since the character was not found remove it from the char array and let our counter know one less char to find.
        counter++;
        charsToRemove.push(char);
      }
    }
    //Do the removal of characters no longer found in the string.
    for (var index = 0; index < charsToRemove.length; index++) {
      charsCopy.splice(charsCopy.indexOf(charsToRemove[index]), 1);
    }
  }
  return locations;
}
```

I dont think this is the optimal way of doing it, so if speed is of the essence, you might need to optimize it, or if anybody else can help out?

I dont think I implemented the function recursiveFindAllCombinations correctly, since it uses the global variable result, I just didn't manage to figure out how to incorporate it with the recursive function, let me know if you can!

#### Edit #1

Changed the function recursiveFindAllCombinations to take into account the values must be in the desired order.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.
2 things to note for future readers:
1. I changed      
      var dataAsString = array2d.map(function(d) {
        return d[0] + d[1] + d[2];
      });
to:
      var dataAsString2 = array2d.map(function(row) {
        return row.reduce(function(item, acc) {
          return (acc = item + acc);
        });
      });
2. if given string can contain same letters, change location from object to something else(multidimensional array, where each row represents letter)